# Edit and continue Option won't work right let editing but compiler ignores

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Trying to get EDIT & CONTINUE option work in my project
Im working with VS19 its a web project with angular at the client side in vs Code (if it's metter)

so I'v read the answers about this topic, And none of them helped my case.

this is my state right now

Enable Edit and Continue - CHECKED
Enable Native Edit and Continue - UNCHECKED
Apply changes on continue (Native) - UNCHECKED
Warn about stale code (Native Only) - UNCHECKED

The result is that I can edit my code but the compiler ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time finally find it, I was actually missing a specific environment  variable in the pool server that the project was belong too.